# android parser xml with xmlpullparser get need element

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

i don't know why I can't post my code.
so this is my problem.
this is xml
[image]

this is xmlpullparser to get natalie img
[image]

this is result
[image]

but result get img of natalie and phil like image I post. why that?
and how to get just img of natalie.
thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set **check to false** in:

```
if(check==true){
// do your work
check=false;
}
```